# PHP error "Notice: Use of undefined constant row - assumed 'row'" MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant row - assumed 'row'

Relevant Code [PHP]:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo BuildDisplay($row['name'], $row['price'], row['link'], $sc);
            if ($sc = 4) {
                $sc = 1;
            } else {
                $sc = ($sc + 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>No Products Available!<p>";
    }
```

Comment: Typo `row['link']`.

Comment: Yup missing dollar sign. Voting to close as typographic error

Comment: Also `$sc = 4` will always evaluate as true, you aren't comparing there. Two `==`s compares, one sets.

Comment: How do I fix the that error, chris85?

Comment: @chris85 How do I fix that error where $sc is always 4?

Comment: Use two `=`s. e.g. `if ($sc == 4) {`. or three if you want to be strict on the variable type as well. The `=` is an assignment operator, `==` and `===` are comparison operators. You can read about operators here, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php, and specific comparison here, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

Comment: Change row['link'] to $row['link']

Answer (score 7):

`row['link']` is missing a dollar sign: `$row['link']`